# When to use wäre and when to use hätte?

Tags: word-order

The following sentence; "*I would have stayed longer if I had known that you would be here*" contains 'would have' and 'If..had'  and  'would be here'.

For the '..would have..' and '.. had known' we  could use wäre or hätte but which do we use exactly, where and why?

Thanks.

Comment: Hi @Jim4567. Try it. If you get stuck, tell us where and why. And please take the [tour](https://german.stackexchange.com/tour).

Comment: What is your best guess, and why do you think it might be wrong?

Comment: My guess is 'had known' is hätte and 'would have' is wäre.

Comment: *If I had known* is *wenn ich gewusst hätte* or *hätte ich gewusst*. Both mean the same, the latter is more elegant.

Answer (score 5):

Whether you have to use *wäre* or *hätte* depends entirely on the verb. In German, we use the axuiliaries *sein* and *haben* to form the perfect tenses of different kinds of verbs. The rule of thumb is that *sein* goes with **intransitive verbs that denote movement or a change of state** and *haben* for almost all of the remaining verbs. Check your favourite grammar source or  [this link](https://deutsch.lingolia.com/en/grammar/verbs/sein-haben) for some more informartion, and here are a few examples for you:

> ich gehe *(I walk / am walking)* --- ich **bin** gegangen *(I went / have gone)*--- ich **wäre** gegangen *(I would have gone)*
>
> du siehst *(you see / are seeing)* --- du **hast** gesehen *(you saw / have seen)* ---- du **hättest** gesehen *(you would have seen)*
>
> er bleibt *(he stays / is staying)* --- er **ist** geblieben *(he stayed / has stayed)* --- er **wäre** geblieben *(he would have stayed)*